Using JSZip with async dynamic imports
I am working on an Angular 18 project that uses JSZip to compress multiple .txt files into an archive. I was previously using the "usual" JSZip syntax like such:
import JSZip from "jszip";
export class ScriptDatabase {
  // My class code...

  exportDatabase(): Promise<Blob> {
    const zip = new JSZip();
    for (const [id, archive] of this.archives) {
      zip.file(`${id}.txt`, archive.exportArchive());
    }
    return zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"});
  }
}

I tried to convert this into a dynamic async import to reduce the final bundle size of my application, as JSZip is actually quite a big library. I tried something like this at first:
  async exportDatabase(): Promise<Blob> {
    const JSZip = await import('jszip');
    const zip = new JSZip();
    for (const [id, archive] of this.archives) {
      zip.file(`${id}.txt`, archive.exportArchive());
    }
    return await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
  }

But my issue is that apparently the JSZip constant is actually a JSZip object, so I can't call new on that, as it has no constructor.
So I tried to use the JSZip constant as an actual JSZip instance like so:
  async exportDatabase(): Promise<Blob> {
    const JSZip = await import('jszip');
    for (const [id, archive] of this.archives) {
      JSZip.file(`${id}.txt`, archive.exportArchive());
    }
    return await JSZip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
  }

My IDE stopped complaining, and the app actually built, but when I tried executing the method, I got this error: ERROR TypeError: JSZip.file is not a function.
And sure enough, when I tried to console log this object, it seems like I got a strange, incomplete version of the JSZip object, and I can only use loadAsync on it. So it's very clear that I'm not using this correctly.
So now I'm stumped. What's the correct syntax to use JSZip with dynamic imports?

You can try the below method for dynamically importing scripts to angular application.
First configure the root script you need, to be moved to the assets folder, so that it can be dynamically imported.
     ...
     "options": {
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "./node_modules/jszip/dist",
            "output": "."
          }
        ],
        ...

Then we can create a script tag programmatically and trigger the logic to happen on load of the script.
ngOnInit() {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'jszip.min.js';
  script.onload = () => {
    const zip = new (window as any).JSZip();

    zip.file('Hello.txt', 'Hello World\n');

    const img: any = zip.folder('images');
    // img.file('smile.gif', imgData, { base64: true });

    zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content: any) {
      // see FileSaver.js
      console.log(content);
      // saveAs(content, 'example.zip');
    });
  };
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hmm, this implementation means that I will have to go from a reusable class to a per-component approach, which I'm not a fan of in my context. Also, wouldn't that code mean that the DOM will get bigger and bigger with duplicate 
@BSoD if the script already is inserted bypass the insert logic and directly create the zip since jszip will be available
